# Cannot FIND anything

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I cannot find entries from the same column inside itself. Why? What is wrong with my code? I get the error that types are not compatible because it finds Nothing for the first entry.

```
Dim Namensspalte As Range, firstEntry As Range, secondEntry As Range
Set Namensspalte = iMAw.Range("E2:E1700")
With Namensspalte
For Each c In Namensspalte
    Set firstEntry = .Find(c, xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not firstEntry Is Nothing Then
        firstEntry.Offset(0, 3).Value = firstEntry.Offset(0, -4).Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
    Set secondEntry = .FindNext(c)
    If Not secondEntry Is Nothing Then
        secondEntry.Offset(0, 4).Value = secondEntry.Offset(0, -4).Value
    End If
Next
End With
```

Comment: you did not `Dim c`. Do you have `Option Explicit` activated ?

Comment: There is no **SET** for **IMAw**

Comment: c is declared in the For-Each Statement. Now I added it before, but I still get the same error. What can I do? I am going crazy here. How is it possible that a value from the same table is not findable inside itself?

There is a Set for IMAW, this is just the relevant part of the code

Comment: I have also tried .Cells.Find instead of .Find, it still cannot find the first value

Answer (score 1):

This should work properly :

```
Sub test_HausUkrop()

Dim Namensspalte As Range, firstEntry As Range, secondEntry As Range, _
    c As Range, FirstAddress As String
Set Namensspalte = iMAw.Range("E2:E1700")
With Namensspalte
    For Each c In .Cells
        Set firstEntry = .Find(What:=c.Value2, _
                                After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False, _
                                SearchFormat:=False)
        If Not firstEntry Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = firstEntry.Address
            firstEntry.Offset(0, 3).Value = firstEntry.Offset(0, -4).Value

            Set secondEntry = .FindNext(firstEntry)
            'Look until you find again the first result
            If Not secondEntry Is Nothing Then
                If secondEntry.Address <> FirstAddress Then
                    secondEntry.Offset(0, 4).Value = secondEntry.Offset(0, -4).Value
                Else
                End If
            Else
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Error"
        End If
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately, now that you are comparing it by address instead of the value, I just get Error-Msgbox for every iteration

Comment: @HausUkrop : What do you mean by comparing it by address? And you message will pop up every time you have a value that doesn't have a duplicate in the column...

Comment: But the error-box is if the first entry is nothing, not the second one.

I am not looking for duplicates, I just want to go through a sorted table and mark for every entry whether it is the first or second occurence in a column with an Offset of 3 and 4 respectively

Comment: @HausUkrop : Ok, it might be that `.Value` take the format into account, so I changed it to `.Value2`. Let me know! BTW, **did you reference `iMAw`?** because it is not defined in the code that I've posted, but I guess that it is in yours!